# Account authentication false access request during creating oauth token googleAnalyticsR

Tags: r, google-analytics, oauth, google-oauth, google-analytics-api

I have a problem with the creation of an oauth token for Google Analytics for a Shiny web app.

When I run this script to create a token (like described here [googleanalytics R Setup](http://code.markedmondson.me/googleAnalyticsR/articles/setup.html) in the Video)

```
library(googleAnalyticsR)

my_client_id = "XXXXXX"
my_client_secret = "XXXXXX"


options(googleAuthR.webapp.client_id = my_client_id)
options(googleAuthR.webapp.client_secret = my_client_secret)

devtools::reload(pkg = devtools::inst("googleAnalyticsR"))

ga_auth()
```

A browser window pops up like it should for authentication in the browser. 
But I should not allow access to my project but for the default "GCP project for googleAnalyticsR" project.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get it worked with a workaround. I just changed the client-id in the url on the authentication website.